# Vue.js; How to get cookies that used by another frame?

Tags: vue.js, cookies, frontend

I have Google sign in button that opens new window for authorization. Can I get cookies from that frame? If the answer is yes, the next question "how?" :)

Picture below shows my cookies (localhost) and cookies that came from Google auth.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, these cookies are from another domain. For security reasons, you can and never will be able to read cookies that are not from your domain.

Think about the consequences it would have if you could: people logging in on your website through some OAuth service for instance, would basically "lose" all the cookie data to your website's JavaScript context since your website happens to include some iframe/image/script from another domain. It would be able to read all cookie values and copy a login session for instance, which might be stored in it.